# How do I get the member function pointer of a destructor?

Tags: c++, destructor, pointer-to-member, c++03

Assume I have

```
struct X {
  ~X() {}
};
```

What's the type of and how do I get the member function pointer of `X::~X()` in C++03?

I don't want to actually call it, just use in SFINAE to figure if there exists a destructor for a given type.

Comment: A destructor **always** exists...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: But, as an actual function? When I pop an `int` from the stack, there's no `int::~int` function called.

Comment: @bitmask: `int` is no `class`, so there is no _destructor_ for it.

Comment: @bitmask: The C++ standard explicitly disagrees with you (sort of); according to the end of section [class.dtor], the following is valid: `typedef int I;
I* p;
p->I::~I();`.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I'd imagine such an instruction wouldn't result in any actual code in the resulting binary, as there's nothing to do for built-in types, right? But I guess this means I can scratch the idea of implementing something like `has_trivial_destructor` in this fashion anyway.

Comment: @Oli: That's a "pseudo-destructor call" and the syntax is valid, but it doesn't call anything. [expr.pseudo] says "The only effect is the evaluation of the postfix-expression before the dot or arrow."

Comment: @bitmask: `has_trivial_destructor` requires compiler support. Not all type traits can be done with pure C++, and this is one of them. If you really *feel* you need this, read your compiler documentation and see if it has that trait. (You can cheat by downloading boost type traits and looking at their implementation for your compiler, no need to actually add the dependency to the code).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't get the function pointer of a destructor nor a constructor. Nevertheless a destructor always exist for a type, and you can't detect if its `private` with as access specifiers are not considered by *SFINAE*.

On the subject of invoking what would be the destructor of a scalar type, the standard says *[class.dtor]/16*:

> [Note:the notation for explicit call of a destructor can be used for any scalar type name (5.2.4). Allowing this makes it possible to write code without having to know if a destructor exists for a given type. For example,
>
> typedef int I;
>
> I* p;
>
> p->I::~I();
>
> —end note]

Comment: Thanks. My motivation was that I can speed up a particular part of a data structure if I don't call the destructors of some objects. So I tried to decide if there is a non-trivial destructor. Any clues?

Comment: @bitmask: Since your question is about _C++03_, your best bet is with `boost::has_trivial_destructor` type trait with works only if the compiler provides an appropriate intrinsic. But if a destructor is trivial, I figure call it anyway and let the compiler optimize it away...

Comment: Well, I have to live with a crippled C++ subset, as I have no boost and no C++11. I don't have to destroy one object but a bunch of objects but have to do nothing if they are trivial, so I don't expect the iteration to be optimised away, so I want to bake that into the code.

Comment: @bitmask: See if your crippled compiler has an intrinsic already... otherwise all bets are off

Comment: It's actually g++, but I cannot use boost/11 for other reasons.

Comment: @bitmask: And you do believe that the performance cost is on destruction? How did you get to this conclusion? If the destructor is trivial, the compiler will see an empty loop and most probably optimize it away. Milage will vary, but you can look at the generated code and see if the loop has been removed from the function.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: Yes, I tried this for a small example (so that I could actually make sense of the assembler) and it seems to be correctly optimised away with at least -O1. However, as you say, my mileage will vary, as I don't see a good way to make sure it will work correctly for the actual code. Still, I don't seem to have other options, so thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @bitmask: Trust the compiler, my assumption is that the loop that deletes the object will not have much logic. If that is the case, then no matter how complex the code is around the loop, the loop would be simple to optimize.