# How virtual mechanism works in the case of virtual destructor

Tags: c++, virtual-destructor

[How do I get the member function pointer of a destructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10858998/how-do-i-get-the-member-function-pointer-of-a-destructor)

here some-one answered  that **we can't get the function pointer of a destructor**
then how the virtual mechanism work in the below code. Is virtual constructor is saved in the virtual table or not?? if not then how virtual mechanism work in the case of virtual destructor?

```
#include<stdio.h>
class Base
{
    public:
    Base()
    {
          printf("C-Base\n");
    }

    virtual ~Base()
    {
           printf("Base\n");
    }
 };

 class Derived:public Base
 {
     public:
     Derived()
    {
         printf("C-DErived\n");
     }
     ~Derived()
     {
         printf("DErived\n");
     }
 };

int main()
{

     Base *b=new Derived();
     delete b;
 }
```

in this code if we not use virtual in Base class Destructor Derived class destructor will not called.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When someone says that you can't get a pointer to the destructor it means that there is no source-code-level syntax for this. But under the hood the destructor is still an ordinary function, which is indeed typically accessed through a pointer stored in the virtual table.

In other words, it is specifically *you*, who can't obtain such a pointer. The compiler itself has no problems obtaining it. *Quod licet Iovi non licet bovi*.

Comment: @Armen Tsirunyan: OK, but I see both spellings being used.

Answer (score 5):

Just because **you** can't get a pointer to the destructor, doesn't mean the compiler can't for its own internal, nefarious purposes.

(As a side note, the compiler often generates more than one version of the destructor, with more than one entry in the vtable, which makes it incompatible with normal function pointers.)

Comment: > more than one version of the destructor < Why? I'm just curious

Comment: @Roddy There's quite a few reasons why more than one destructor might be needed. One: when a class has a virtual base somewhere, only the most derived class's destructor should call its destructor, so there will be two destructors: a "full-object destructor" that calls the destructor of the virtual base, and a "sub-object destructor" that doesn't.

Comment: Two: when a class has an overloaded operator new and delete, that operator delete must be used to free its memory even when deleting through a base pointer. GCC implements this by having a "non-deleting destructor" used for stack objects, and a "deleting destructor" that basically calls the non-deleting destructor and then calls the correct operator delete for the full-object.