# c++98 / SFINAE: How to detect if a derived class has its destructor declared in private?

Tags: c++, boost, type-traits, boost-mpl

How to detect if a derived class has its destructor declared `private`?

I'm trying to use a SFINAE trick to detect if the destructor is accessible but I keep being failing.

I took a look at boost type traits and I did not find any `has_private_destructor()`.

Is it only possible?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why you need this?

Comment: I want to prevent users to call delete() on the object they have created, since my framework will call delete() on their object, and only my framework know when the object can be deleted.
So users must inherit from one of my class, I'm able to call delete on this base class since I'm friend with it. But I want them to implement their derived destructor as private to prevent them at compile time to call delete on this derived object.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10859012/168175 seems to suggest that this isn't possible

Comment: Is the "cpp98" in your title meant to refer to C++98? Referring to the language as "cpp" is confusing, since (a) that's not its name, and (b) "cpp" often refers to the C preprocessor.